# vb word counter richtextbox covering multiple lines

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am programming novel management software, and I need to be able to keep track of the amount of words in the richtextbox accurately. This is what I have so far

```
Dim Change As Integer
Dim Count As Integer

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Change = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").ToLookup(Function(x) x).Count()
    'Add 1 to the variable Change every time the space bar is pressed

    Count = Change

    If RichTextBox1.Text = "" Then
        Count = 0
        'If the textbox is empty, the word count is 0
    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text.EndsWith(" ") = True Then
        Count = Change - 1
        'take one away from the wordcount variable when the last character is a space
    End If

    ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = Count
    'Display the wordcount
End Sub
```

How do I get the code to keep going on multiple lines? So far, the code only runs on the text on the first line. If the user hits enter then keeps typing, the the word count doesnt count the first word on each subsequent lines

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @roryap opps. i edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in the keydown handler. There may be some special cases for leading and trailing spaces, unless it can be off by 1, and backspaces should be handled.

```
If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Or e.KeyValue = Keys.Back Then
  ss = rText1.Text.Split
  txCount.Text = UBound(ss) + 1
  End If
```

Comment: e.keyvalue refuses to work for me. No matter what, i keep getting the error "keyvalue is not a member of system.windows.forms.keyPressEventArgs"

Comment: The keypress event uses KeyPressEventArgs and has the parameter e.KeyChar. The keydown event uses KeyEventArgs as has the parameter e.KeyValue.